# Sync/ replicate more than two databases in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, odoo, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

I have 5 users which uses 5 different servers(using openerp), each one uses the same database copy. Whenever the user enters data to his database, then it should sync to the 6th server's database an then sync the data in the 6th database to all other 4 users databases. So any data entry in any database should sync to the other databases running in different servers. Is that possible? how can I achieve it?

Edit:
I found Bucardo, but it need primary key for every table. But in openerp, there are many2many relation tables which doesn't have a primary key.

Comment: 1. What should happen if 2 users make conflicting changes to the same data? 2. How much of the replication pages of the official website and wiki have you read?

Comment: Did you find something that worked??

Comment: @timothy, I have to drop that project. I found a module in openerp truck called base_synchro. It it is not in a stable state so I have to  modify most of its functionality for managing workflow and also deleting a record.It was almost working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is called master-master or multi-master replication:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-master_replication#PostgreSQL

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling

You can also check out SymmetricDS or Daffodil which let you sync over HTTP.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Let me check on it

Answer (score 1):

A pure PostgreSQL installation supports currently only single master replication.
However you may achieve multi-master replication by installing additional tools http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Clustering.

You should also check out Pg documentation on this topic [Chapter 25. High Availability, Load Balancing, and Replication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Let me check on it